# Football Data - ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I am working with a large Football dataset and currently logging the team outcomes for each match played. However, there are a couple of entries with a date instead of a score:

[image: screenshot of data in DataFrame]

I have implemented another block of code in the function to change the data into a score before appending it to the list:

```
def get_results(self): 
        #split results and add to lists
        home_goal = []
        away_goal = []
        home_match_outcome = []
        away_match_outcome = []
        home_points = []
        away_points = []
            
        split_result = self.x["Result"].str.split("-") #split results at '-' to separate numbers

        for i, res in enumerate(tqdm(split_result, desc = "Splitting results")):
             
            try: 
                self.home_goal.append(int(res[0][0])) #convert to int to add goals together -- default type is str
                #print("Away goals: ", res[1][0])
                away_goal.append(int(res[1][0]))

                #Determine match outcomes
                #Win
                if int(res[0][0]) > int(res[1][0]):
                    home_match_outcome.append("Win")
                    home_points.append(3) #3 points for a win 

                    away_match_outcome.append("Loss")   
                    away_points.append(0)           
                #Draw
                elif int(res[0][0]) == int(res[1][0]):
                    home_match_outcome.append("Draw")
                    home_points.append(1) #1 point for a draw

                    away_match_outcome.append("Draw")  
                    away_points.append(1)   
                #Loss    
                else:
                    home_match_outcome.append("Loss")
                    home_points.append(0) #0 points for a loss

                    away_match_outcome.append("Win")  
                    away_points.append(3) 
            except IndexError:
                l = list(res)
                for c in l:
                    x = int(c[0])
                    y = int(c[1])
                self.home_goal.append(x) #convert to int to add goals together -- default type is str
                            #print("Away goals: ", res[1][0])
                away_goal.append(y)
                if x > y:
                    home_match_outcome.append("Win")
                    home_points.append(3) #3 points for a win 
                    away_match_outcome.append("Loss")   
                    away_points.append(0)   
                elif x == y:
                    home_match_outcome.append("Draw")
                    home_points.append(1) #1 point for a draw

                    away_match_outcome.append("Draw")  
                    away_points.append(1)
                else:
                    home_match_outcome.append("Loss")
                    home_points.append(0) #0 points for a loss

                    away_match_outcome.append("Win")  
                    away_points.append(3) 
                
        
        #add lists to existing dataframe/set
        self.x["Home_Goals"] = home_goal
        self.x["Away_Goals"] = away_goal
        self.x["Home_Match_Outcome"] = home_match_outcome
        self.x["Home_Points"] = home_points
        self.x["Away_Match_Outcome"] = away_match_outcome
        self.x["Away_Points"] = away_points 
        
        return self.x #display modified dataset
```

When run, I get the following error in home_goal: `ValueError: Length of values (97495) does not match length of index (97494)`

Even if I leave out the 2021 league data, the error still appears.

If the goals are omitted when I run this block of code, it works fine, but I want to have them displayed in the Pandas DataFrame. Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but your exception handling there looks *very* risky. You are modifying variables then, if an exception happens anywhere in that big block, you repeat *everything* in the except block. What if home_goal was already assigned to?

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that. How would you suggest I change it to avoid this?

Comment: Split of the body of your loop: First, handle the messy input with the goal of just computing `x` and `y`. No `append`ing or anything. Then afterwards to all the loss/win scoring. But, i have no idea what you actually do with these date fields, how they are supposed to determine the scoring somehow.. The information just doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't been clear. This function is splitting the results into home and away goals. The match outcome is determined for each team based on the number of goals scored per game, and the number of points awarded; these new pieces of data are then added to the DataFrame.

Comment: For the date fields, I've split the first two values (e.g. 17 Jan) and am using that as the score (1-7). I have tested the code separately for those rows with a date rather than a result, and it works fine. Also wanted to say that this function does work on a smaller dataset (i.e. one league).

Comment: Why would the date be equal to the digits of the match score?! Even if it's just as a random filler, it would be highly biased against the away team winning.